# How do you disable Debug (Toolbar) for Ajax calls in Symfony2?

Tags: php, ajax, debugging, symfony, controller

Does anyone know how to disable the debug toolbar for Ajax calls?

I have tried this:

```
$this->container->get('profiler')->disable();
```

but didn't work.

I have a controller that returns a string (json encoded data). And in the development environment I get

```
<div class="debug"></div>
```

at the end of string which breaks my code.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you return a json string anyway just use [`JsonResponse`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/introduction.html#creating-a-json-response) in your controller.

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

$response = new JsonResponse();
$response->setData(array(
    'data' => 123
));
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: thanks, I also figured that while crawling Symfony's source but I still get an extra "<div class="debug"></div>" after the response. That only happens in dev environment (using app_dev.php) I am trying to find where that extra string comes from.

Comment: Then it probably comes from your code, symfony doesn't add this kind of code.

Comment: exactly :) a legacy code was left within our library. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

found a leftover function from a legacy debug alternative that we have written to symfony's own debug toolbar in one of our listeners. so there was no symfony issue but a developer error.